# Jupyter Configurable nbextensions list is empty

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I installed `conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_nbextensions_configurator` and ran `jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --user` in my venv, but the nbextensions menu is empty. I've restarted notebook a few times, no luck. How can I get the menu to show up so that I can click and select TOC, etc.?

System details:

Windows 10, Firefox 
conda   4.8.2  
Python  3.8.3 
jupyter 1.0.0   pypi_0  pypi 
jupyter_client  6.1.3   py_0    conda-forge 
jupyter_console 6.1.0   py_1    conda-forge 
jupyter_contrib_core    0.3.3   py_2    conda-forge 
jupyter_core    4.6.3   py38h32f6830_1  conda-forge 
jupyter_nbextensions_configurator 0.4.1 py38_0  conda-forge

```
(myenv) C:\path>jupyter nbextension list
Known nbextensions:
  config dir: C:\path\.jupyter\nbconfig
    notebook section
      nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main enabled
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main
      jupyter-js-widgets/extension disabled
      jupyter-vega/index disabled
    tree section
      nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main enabled
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main
  config dir: C:\path\anaconda3\envs\myenv\etc\jupyter\nbconfig
    notebook section
      jupyter-js-widgets/extension enabled
      - Validating: ok
      jupyter-vega/index enabled
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X jupyter-vega/index
      nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main enabled
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main
    tree section
      nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main enabled
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/issues/1196), in an open issue on Github

I ran the following in Anaconda prompt:

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --user
```

(note that `conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_nbextensions_configurator` had already been run in the prompt)

And then launched notebook and the extensions were available:
[image]

Comment: Saved me after an hour of trying to get this up!

Comment: Python 3.9 update: I also had to replace `template_path` with `template_paths` in a few files, as described in the open issue on Gihub ([Link](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/issues/1529#issuecomment-814677078)). Then I also had to run `jupyter contrib nbextension install --user` in the Anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 4):

If someone's still struggling - like me - use this, worked fine for me:
https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/issues/1196#issuecomment-903668248

---

In anaconda navigator - go to environments (below HOME) - select base - open terminal

then paste this code

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
```

then

```
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
```

after that

```
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
```

then Refresh applications
--> check nbextensions

Comment: When I give command - jupyter contrib nbextension install --user, I get - jupyter-contrib: error: argument --user: expected one argument.  

What is problem here?