# Jupyter Notebook TOC not showing up

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I created a new environment in Anaconda, and I cannot get Jupyter Notebooks TOC to work. I tried the answers in a similar question at [Jupyter Configurable nbextensions list is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62763031/jupyter-configurable-nbextensions-list-is-empty/62799367#62799367).

I initially created my new env in Anaconda prompt like this:

```
conda create --name py38 python=3.8
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
conda config --env --set channel_priority strict
conda install -c conda-forge notebook
ipython kernel install --name "py38" --user
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --user
```

**Expected Behavior #1**
[image]

**Actual Behavior #1**

[image]

**Expected Behavior #2**

[image]

**Actual Behavior #2**

[image]

I did notice that when launching `jupyter notebook` from Anaconda prompt, it kept printing `` Config option `template_path` not recognized by `` into the prompt. Notebook launched fine, but the TOC switch wasn't there and the Nbextentions tab looked different than in my other environments. (I tried toggling TOC on/off in the Nbextensions tab.) See the expected/actual behavior screen grabs shown above.

Following [this discussion relating to `template path` on Github](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/issues/1529), I tried the to create a new environment using the following (in Anaconda prompt), specifically down-grading `nbconvert`, but the same Actual Behaviors as above remained.

```
conda create --name test2 python=3.8
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
conda config --env --set channel_priority strict
conda install -c conda-forge notebook
conda install -c conda-forge nbconvert==5.6.1
ipython kernel install --name "test2" --user
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --user
```

**How can I get the TOC in my new environment in Jupyter Notebook?**

Comment: Check whether you have `nbconvert==5.6.1` as requested. [This thread](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/issues/1529) attributes the `template_path` error to nbconvert 6. Did your subsequent `conda` calls update it on you?